# How to set Child Nodes to Parent Nodes in TreeView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = TreeView1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    TreeLogic bl = new TreeLogic();
    TreeNode root= new TreeNode(input);
    ds = bl.getChild(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TreeNode tnode = new TreeNode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());
        tnode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
        root.ChildNodes.Add(tnode);
    }
}
```

Child nodes not displays when i select parent node. Can any one tell why?

Comment: You are doing all the addition inside the `Treeview1_selectedNodeChanged` event. Did you fire that event first? Try debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** If you are trying to add those new nodes as children of the selected node, you're doing it wrong =)  You need to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    TreeNode tnode = new TreeNode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());
    tnode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
    // Add the new TreeNodes underneath the currently selected TreeNode.
    TreeView1.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Add(tnode);
}
TreeView1.SelectedNode.Expand();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are adding the child nodes to root, which is a node created only locally and which does not belong to your TreeView.